# How to approach program design with respect to data strucutres and algorimths - is there an equivelant of the OO design process for d.s.'s + algs?

Tags: design, programming-practices, performance, efficiency, algorithm-analysis

My applogies for probably the worst written body of text I have produced in my life and many thanks to those willing to plough through it all.

I was (and still am) not able to clearly express what I was asking for, since by the nature of my question I cannot be clear about what exactly it is I am after. Fundementally I strongly suspect something in my knowledge of software development is missing, but because "I don't know, what I don't know", I cannot specify what exactly I am looking for (and indeed can't be sure whether such a thing exists) - hence I suppose I am asking for some direction in this matter. I kind of thought if proffessional developers did not know of/ did not use such a thing in the process of desingin code - then there is nothing to know in this respect (and I can stop worrying).

Essentially I fear something akin to having learned to program, but having remained unaware of the subject of proper OO software design. I have studied standard data strucutres and algorithms (to the extent of coverage found in typical undergraduate text books), but can't help feeling that there should be something more. I hence can't help feeling like I've learned the very basics, but not become aware of the data structures and algs. equivelant of OO design. In essence I sort of imagine there is some "process" to solution design (in the context of the d.s.s and algs. side of programming - like there is to the OO design side of coding software - I see them both as being part of the same whole in programming) that informs one about how to go about the task of writing "good" code (in the d.s. and algs aspect of the program code written). I fear in absence of knowledge of such a process/ subject, I would be incompetent as a graduate developer (rather like I would consider a new employee, if his code turned out to be uninformed by the OO design process/ principles). I would consider the code produduced by someone lacking in knowledge of OO design principles/ processes to be "bad code" - and hence him to be incompetent. At the moment I fear my knwolege with respect to the d.s. + algs. side of coding puts me in a similar position. Thus, can anyone tell me what I might yet need to be aware of in this respect?

(Another way of putting my question might be if I were to say: "Object Oriented design principles and patterns, is to programming, what "...", is to data strucutres and algorithms". Could anyone tell me what one might complete this sentence with, or whether there is nothing to consider here)

Comment: Maybe I have not had enough caffeine today, but I am having a difficult time following your question -- maybe editing it for brevity (efficiency?) would help.

Comment: @man of I apologize for some of the other members'  comments. This site is evolving into more of a high in tech low in human values environment.

Comment: @DominicMcDonnell could you please also look up the meta post about how unfriendly and judgemental stackexchange is becoming of late? Would you post the same comment if your facebook account was linked here and this op guy's pic was there in the question?

Comment: @dbza: SO is supposed to be respectful and professional, but primarily it is a place for high quality questions and answers. Bad questions need to be closed, politely if possible. Ask a question on meta if you need further clarification.

Comment: @dbza - and you think the student will be better off spared the rod? The core essence of this question is severely flawed, since it's based off of the absurd assumption that OOD can be approached and checked off systematically. Based on the tone of the original question, I doubted that a subtle correction would be sufficient.

Comment: completely agree with @david.pfx . But this shouldn't be involving personal insults. That is what we have been doing in this thread in  two different occasions, I'm glad to see both of them removed now. Maintaining quality is one thing, but that does not mean by being rude. There are options like downvote that you can use designed to help to meet all your quality requirements, not personal insults and mockery.

Comment: @telastyn If you only meant "sublte correction" it is a good thing to be a good teacher, I appreciate it.

Comment: @dbza, you have completely misconstrued my comment. It was supposed to be helpful. From wikipedia: "psychological phenomenon in which people are unable to internalize their accomplishments. Despite external evidence of their competence, those with the syndrome remain convinced that they are frauds and do not deserve the success they have achieved." In other words, I was telling man of to stop doubting. I struggled a lot with this and I found it very helpful when someone pointed it out to me.

Comment: I work with some very competent and professional people. They work well as a team, and their code is nothing if not well-written. However, there are still serious performance problems, as is likely when any software gets large. The problem is, programmers are taught how to find logic bugs, but not speed bugs. They are only taught platitudes, like "profile", or "measure", or quotations from Knuth. The reason is, their teachers have not been responsible for performance of large software. The method I recommend is [*this*](http://stackoverflow.com/a/378024/23771).

Comment: My appologies for potentally abusing the forum system, maybe this is not the style of question I should have put on stack exchange - just I'm not sure where else I could seek such advice? Didn't quite realise this might not be an appropriate approach, as homer simpson said "it's my first day..."    ; )

Answer (score 9):

First things first, OOD isn't something you can approach systematically. There's no checkboxes for something that will vary based on who is doing it and what environment you're in. So your assumption that efficiency will follow a similar path is flawed.

In practice, very few companies care very much about efficient code. Those blurbs are (very often) put in by HR people or middle managers who have no idea what it means. Companies want your software to work. They want it to keep working. And unless your company actually has hard requirements on performance and scalability, you have a lot of leeway about how your solutions are implemented.

But let's for a moment consider what it does actually mean in the minority of jobs where it matters. You are right that "efficient code" is focused primarily on the time and space complexity of the algorithms and data structures in your books. Unfortunately, it is seldom clear cut what your inputs will look like, or what metric you're optimizing for (can you take up more memory in exchange for faster performance? Can you sacrifice accuracy for disk space?). In practice, the choices you face (both in efficiency and OOD) will be a series of trade-offs. There will be no check boxes to mark off. There is very often no single correct answer.

You'll need to make some assumptions about what your input looks like, and will eventually look like. You'll need to make some assumptions about what is important to (most of) your users. And then you'll need to make your best guess about the appropriate solution to balance meeting all of your demands while using as little of your resources.

Comment: Don't forget profiling, and Knuth's quote about "premature optimization is the root of all evil."

Comment: @Snowman - I suppose, though maybe 75% of professionals I've worked with had never run a profiler. Though that's a good point on Knuth.

Comment: On a side note I think we could be a bit more friendly and keep SE a warm welcoming place for newbies. "And now I'm nearly dead sure that you have no idea." is rude. whatever Ks your reputation here is.

Comment: There are plenty of approaches to use [formal specifications in OO systems](http://www.scielo.br/scielo.php?script=sci_arttext&pid=S0104-65001998000200004), I used to know an analyst who used them to produce OO designs that were very good. Just because most developers bang stuff together that mostly works doesn't mean there isn't better ways of doing it (if much less fun!). I recall being taught formal analysis stuff, and it was dull.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "OOD isn't something you can approach systematically"?

Comment: @Dunk - I'm not sure I can well. It's like saying that painting a picture is something that anyone can do by following a process. Even if one person has a solid process to design software, that process won't work for everyone and (in my experience) won't work for all software problems. So to say "OOD is a process" is nonsensical to me.

Comment: @Telastyn I think I understand what you mean, but I didn't mean to suggest such a mechanical process. I kind of gave the impression I saw it as a very literal series of steps to "check off" one by one - i regret how that would be read. rather I meant to describe a "process" (in loose terms), as perhaps more like a phase, within which one might regard OOD as an agregation of a **set** of different considerations to make (in no particular order), as a possible solution is modeled - which ultimately could allow you to be confident (once you've visited/ re-visited each consideration) you will

Comment: be likely to arrive at a "good" OO design? Would this represent a closer descritption, or am I still way off?

Comment: @manof - I'm perhaps not the best person to ask in that regard. It took a half-dozen years or so of people telling me my designs were awesome (and me merely not hating them) to get to fair confidence that new ones will be good.